# ClaimsIdentity: Add claim with type enum (or other strong type)

Tags: c#, enums, claims-based-identity

Is there a way to add claims that are not strings? (In my case, adding a claim that has an enum value is what I want, but I'm wondering about various types in general.)

For example, this is what I want to do:

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity("my_auth_type");
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("my_claim_name", MyEnum.SomeValue));
```

The second line is not valid because the Claim constructor is expecting a string as the second parameter. I could call `enumValue.ToString()`, but ideally it seems like a better practice to leave it strongly typed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can define an extension method like this :

```
    public static void AddEnumClaim<T>(this ClaimsIdentity identity, String type, T enumvalue)
            where T : struct
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException("AddEnumClaim must be an enum");
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(type, enumvalue.ToString()));
    }
```

and call it with :

```
identity.AddEnumClaim("my_claim_name", MyEnum.SomeValue);
```

Comment: I guess I was wondering if the underlying value could be stored as a stronger type, but I suppose the answer is no because Value is a string on the Claim type. Thanks anyway!